# Translation of ''bobinus''

Tags: sens, traduction, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, littérature

The sentence is: "C'était des assiettées monstres et des hourras à plus finir... à faire crouler tout le ***bobinus***..."

What is the meaning of ***bobinus***? Is it a variation of ***bobinard***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no reference but a variation from *bobinard*, already used by Céline at least in *Voyage au bout de la nuit*, is indeed a good guess.

TLFi : [Bobinard](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bobinard/1) *Arg.* Cabaret de 2<sup>e</sup> ordre; maison de prostitution. *Bobinard clandestin* (Céline, *Voyage au bout de la nuit*, 1932, p. 283); *virée de bobinard en bobinard* (Céline, *Voyage au bout de la nuit*, 1932, p. 198). Synon. *bordel*

Comment: Sans être déterminant ça semble être aussi le choix d'interprétation qu'on aurait fait dans  [une traduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=qD2B3hUXeZsC&lpg=PP1&dq=Guignol's%20Band%20I&pg=PA210#v=onepage&q=Leicester&f=false) en langue anglaise.

Comment: @Lambie Une référence principale serait une référence vers *bobinus* mais je n'en ai pas. La référence que j'ai ajoutée est une référence accessoire car il s'agit de la définition d'un mot déjà identifié et connu de l'OP.

Comment: @Lambie Stop what?

Comment: @Lambie Why did you write "Please stop it. PLEASE" and then erased your comment?

Comment: @laparole Je pense qu'il s'agit d'un malentendu. Lambie avait écrit quelque chose comme *ces notes de bas de page en petits caractères sont s****** à lire*. J'ai écrit plus loin en réponse *shiantes ?* pour tenter de deviner ce qui se cachait derrière ce mot caché, mais elle l'a mal pris, je ne sais pas vraiment pourquoi.